# Does spring kafka consumer retry messages inside the pool loop?

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka

Are the messages retried inside the pool loop (so the poll won't be called again until error is recovered)? Or, if an error is received, the poll is called again, containing the message that needs to be retried.

I need this information so that i'll know if max.poll.interval should be big enough to contain also the retries that might happen, to avoid rebalances.

From what i see, the poll is called again everytime a retryable exception occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the messages are retried inside the pool loop. If an error is received, the poll is called again with the same message that needs to be retried. Therefore, you should set the max.poll.interval to be big enough to contain the retries that may occur in order to avoid rebalances.

Comment: from what you say, i understand that the poll interval does not need to contain the retries that may occur, because after an error is received, the poll is called again, meaning that a heartbeat will be sent to avoid rebalance and the max.poll.interval timer will restart